# Custom Serialization with Json.net

Tags: c#, json, json.net, serialization, vsphere

I am obtaining information through the vSphere API (SOAP). The responses come back with an array of custom objects and custom properties. Working through it to get what you want can be a bit of a pain, so I started playing around with serializing the returned data to Json. This is working reasonably well, although I am finding it a little hard to group returned data and filter it. Anyway, here is an example json tree:

[image: Example Json Hierarchy Tree]

What I would like help with is formatting this tree so it is more like this

[image: What I Want..]

As you can see, what I am trying to achieve is when serializing from an object to json, I would like to 'relocate' some of the objects. I want to make it easier, i.e. I can search for the json path containing .config.hardware and get all the child information back. I've been reading through the Json.Net documentation, but I'm so confused at the moment, I don't even know where to start!

Comment: Please, do not post code as images

Comment: post the plain Json to understand the structure better

Comment: both images look the same to me ?

Comment: Easiest way is to create a model that matches what you want then populate it with the data you have and the serialize it.

Comment: Understand re the model, however, I dont know what data will be there until it comes in